# Casting varchar to bigint in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to concat two integers together and then cast it as bigint, but SQL Server 2016 is throwing an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint

My table has two columns `idnum int not null` and `innumdb not null`.

In my select query, I am doing the following:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(idnum, idnumdb) AS BIGINT) 
FROM TABLE
```

When I execute the query, some data will be display but then while the query is displaying data, I get the error mentioned above.

I don't understand why since both `idnum` and `idnumdb` are `int` datatype in the table. I am assuming the `concat` function is messing up the data. Any ideas what's going on here? Thanks in advance

Comment: if `idnumdb` is negative the result wont be a valid bigint

Comment: hi Martin,  i checked the data for values < 0 and there are no rows with negative sign.  i dont know which rows is causing the problem either.  some rows are display on the data grid and then the error comes up. so it looks like some rows may be the problem. not sure 100%

Comment: You can use `TRY_CAST()` instead of `CAST()`, and filter to see wich records end up with `NULL` values in the result.

Comment: also concatenating two large ints can can cause overflow. the max signed int has 10 digits so concatenating two of those will be 20 digits and max signed bigint is 19 digits. What are you trying to do with this? It also wont be unique. concatenating 12 and 3 will be the same as 1 and 23

Comment: Check your idnum and idnumdb having [a-z] or Special character.

Comment: Is there any result for: SELECT CONCAT(idnum, idnumdb) 
FROM TABLE
WHERE ISNUMERIC(CONCAT(idnum, idnumdb) ) <> 1

Comment: Why do you want to concat the 2 integers in the first place? Maybe explain us your reason, then we might be able to guide you a better way.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for helping out.  i tried Udai solution of executing
 SELECT CONCAT(idnum, idnumdb) FROM TABLE WHERE ISNUMERIC(CONCAT(idnum, idnumdb) ) <> 1

it turns out that idnumdb has a - sign for a few rows.  i test on idnum only and that was fine.  idnumdb was the problem.  thanks all